# Avoiding bias in randomly generated subtraction problems

Tags: math, python-2.7, random

I'm writing a Python script to generate problems for mental arithmetic drills. The addition and multiplication ones were easy, but I'm running into trouble trying to generate unbiased problems for the subtraction ones.

I want to be able to specify a minimum and maximum value that the minuend (first number) will be -- e.g., for two-digit subtraction it should be between 20 and 99. The subtrahend should also have a range option (11-99, say). The answer needs to be positive and preferably also bounded by a minimum of, say, 10 for this situation.

So:

- 20 < Minuend < 99
- 11 < Subtrahend < 99
- Answer = Minuend - Subtrahend
- Answer >= 10

All the numeric values should be used as variables, of course.

I have these conditions met as follows:

```
ansMin, ansMax = 10, 99
subtrahendMin, minuendMax = 11,99
# the other max and min did not seem to be necessary here,
# and two ranges was the way I had the program set up

answer = randint(ansMin, ansMax)
subtrahend = randint(subtrahendMin, minuendMax - answer)
minuend = answer + subtrahend # rearranged subtraction equation
```

The problem here is that the minuend values wind up being nearly all over 50 because the answer and subtrahend were generated first and added together, and only the section of them that were both in the bottom 25% of the range will get the result below 50%. (Edit: that's not strictly true -- for instance, bottom 1% plus bottom 49% would work, and percentages are a bad way of describing it anyway, but I think the idea is clear.)

I also considered trying generating the minuend and subtrahend values both entirely randomly, then throwing out the answer if it didn't match the criteria (namely, that the minuend be greater than the subtrahend by a value at least greater than the answerMin and that they both be within the criteria listed above), but I figured that would result in a similar bias.

I don't care about it being *perfectly* even, but this is too far off. I'd like the minuend values to be fully random across the allowable range, and the subtrahend values random across the range allowed by the minuends (if I'm thinking about it right, this will be biased in favor of lower ones). I don't think I really care about the distribution of the answers (as long as it's not ridiculously biased). Is there a better way to calculate this?

Comment: Do you want answer >= 10 or answer < 10, It seems that there is contradiction between description and code

Comment: Whoops, I copied half the parameters from the one-digit subtraction function. Fixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of defining what "not biased" means in this case. I assume that what you are looking for is that every possible subtraction problem from the allowed problem space is chosen with equal probability. Quick and dirty approach:

1. Pick random x in [x_min, x_max]
2. Pick random y in [y_min, y_max]
3. If x - y < answer_min, discard **both x and y** and start over.

Note the bold part. If you discard only y and keep the x, your problems will have an uniform distribution in x, not in the entire problem space. You need to ensure that for every valid x there is at least one valid y - this is not the case for your original choice of ranges, as we'll see later.

Now the long, proper approach. First we need to find out the actual size of the problem space.

The allowed set of subtrahends is determined by the minuend:

```
x in [21, 99]
y in [11, x-10]
```

or using symbolic constants:

```
x in [x_min, x_max]
y in [y_min, x - answer_min]
```

We can rewrite that as

```
x in [21, 99]
y = 11 + a
a in [0, x-21]
```

or again using symbolic constants

```
x in [x_min, x_max]
y = y_min + a
a in [0, x - (answer_min + y_min)].
```

From this, we see that valid problems exist only for x >= (answer_min + y_min), and for a given x there are x - (answer_min + y_min) + 1 possible subtrahents.

Now we assume that x_max does not impose any further constraints, e.g. that answer_min + y_min >= 0:

```
x in [21, 99], number of problems:
    (99 - 21 + 1) * (1 + 78+1) / 2
x in [x_min, x_max], number of problems:
    (x_max - x_min + 1) * (1 + x_max - (answer_min + y_min) + 1) / 2
```

The above is obtained using the formula for the sum of an arithmetic sequence. Therefore, you need to pick a random number in the range [1, 4740]. To transform this number into a subtraction problem, we need to define a mapping between the problem space and the integers. An example mapping is as follows:

- 1 <=> x = 21, y = 11
- 2 <=> x = 22, y = 12
- 3 <=> x = 22, y = 11
- 4 <=> x = 23, y = 13
- 5 <=> x = 23, y = 12
- 6 <=> x = 23, y = 11

and so on. Notice that x jumps by 1 when a triangular number is exceeded. To compute x and y from the random number r, find the lowest triangular number t greater than or equal to r, preferably by searching in a precomputed table; write this number as q*(q+1)/2. Then x = x_min + q-1 and y = y_min + t - r.

Complete program:

```
import random

x_min, x_max = (21, 99)
y_min = 11
answer_min = 10

triangles = [ (q*(q+1)/2, q) for q in range(1, x_max-x_min+2) ]
upper = (x_max-x_min+1) * (1 + x_max - (answer_min + y_min) + 1) / 2

for i in range(0, 20):
    r = 1 + random.randrange(0, upper)
    (t, q) = next(a for a in triangles if a[0] >= r)
    x = x_min + q - 1
    y = y_min + t - r
    print "%d - %d = ?" % (x, y)
```

Note that for a majority of problems (around 75%), x will be above 60. This is correct, because for low values of the minuend there are fewer allowed values of the subtrahend.

Comment: Thanks! I've put in the discard approach for the moment, but I'm interested in understanding the complete way to calculate it, so I'll have a look at the full code sometime later.

I was actually *thinking* of uniform distribution of the minuend over its possible values, not caring about the other ones, but on reflection I think this is actually more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of issues with your starting values - if you want the answer to always be greater than 10 - then you need to either increase MinuendMin, or decrease SubtrahendMin because 20-11 is less than 10...  Also you have defined the answer min and max as 3,9 - which means the answer will never be more than 10...

Apart from that I managed to get a nice even distribution of values by selecting the minuend value first, then selecting the subtrahend value based on it and the answerMin:

```
ansMin = 10
minuendMin, minuendMax = 20,99
subtrahendMin = 9;

minuend = randint(minuendMin, minuendMax )
subtrahend = randint(subtrahendMin,(minuend-ansMin) ) 
answer = minuend - subtrahend
```

Comment: This will not actually yield an uniform distribution in the problem space. Problems with a low minuend will be overrepresented.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the values being wrong -- please see my edit, I inadvertently copied half of them from another part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've already got addition working properly. Assuming you have similar restrictions for the addends/sum you could rearrange the factors so that:

```
minuend <= sum
subtrahend <= first addend
answer <= second addend
```

A similar mapping can be made for multiplication/division, if required.